# error playing video in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: plugins, video-player

After playing any video...following msg is shown:  **Required plugin could not be found**  Videos requires to install plugins to play files of the following types:  • MPEG-4 AAC decoder  • H.264 (Main Profile) decoder

Answer (score 3):

For this specific type you can install either `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`  or `gstreamer1.0-libav` Both will enable h.264 & aac decoding. Probably best in long run to just install both.

`sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-libav`

If you wanted to fill out support further you could add the `gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly` package though not needed in this case.